# Automating VPN launch

Tags: linux, vpn, passwords, openvpn, gnu-screen

I've recently set a VPN connection up, between my home computer (Ubuntu 14.10) and a dedicated server (Debian 7.7), using OpenVPN. So far so good.

My question is, how would you go about simplifying / automating the use of this VPN connection ?

In case you're not familiar with OpenVPN, I start it with these commands :

```
cd /etc/openvpn
sudo openvpn client.conf
```

Right after that, I am prompted to enter a password and that's it.

The only two constraints I have are :

- I need to be able to start/stop it manually, when I decide to use it.
- I don't want it to force me to keep a shell opened.

Ideally, a solution similar to starting a service would be the best for me.

My first thought was to do this using screen and a shell script that I could place somewhere in my PATH, so that I could simply launch it any time I want to use the VPN. However, one of the problems is that I have to input a password, and I don't know if there's a way I could retrieve the password from the shell script -- as an argument maybe -- and send it to the screen session.

There might also be other, more elegant, solutions. If you have any, I'm all ears.

Final point, I'm still fairly new to Unix environment, but I'm not afraid of having to learn new concepts and even code my own solution. No holds barred.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ideally, a solution similar to starting a service would be the best for me.

Indeed. In fact,

```
   sudo service openvpn start/stop/restart/status...
```

**does** work, because you have placed your .conf file inside /etc/openvpn. Also, and for the same reason, *openvpn* is started automatically at boot.

Comment: Haha, indeed that is perfect. I had no clue openVPN was worked as a service. Thank you for the information =)